# Find the density of the random variable $Y=X^2$

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

Find the density of the random variable $Y = X^2$, if the random variable $X$ follows a standard normal distribution.

I think I should use mgf to solve it is that right ? what should I do to start ?

Comment: You can use the method of transformations. Or else you can write down an expression (as an integral) of the cdf of $X^2$, and then differentiate.

Comment: How do I use the method of transformations ? I don't have anything to substitute it with ?!

Comment: I almost always prefer to go through the cdf, since the intuition is clearer.  Let $Y=X^2$. We have $\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(|X|\le \sqrt{y})=2\Pr(0\le X\le \sqrt{y})$. Now express as an integral and differentiate under the integral sign.

Answer (score 2):

This $might$ do it... We have that $$F_{X^2}(x) = \textbf{P}(X^2 \leq x) = \textbf{P}(-\sqrt{x} \leq X \leq \sqrt{x}) = 2\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{e^{-x'^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx'$$. Since $f_{X^2}(x) = dF_{X^2}(x)/dx$ it follows that $$ f_{X^2}(x) = \left(\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-x/2} = \frac{e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}$$

Comment: Can you please explain in words what you did

Comment: Oh I didn't think of that, thanks for pointing it out